# WHMCS clients logo

Tags: whmcs

I Have clients.php and clients.tpl
I want to attach here the logo of my clients with a link on the new page to their website. I want the logo to be 5 in a row. I found many examples on Google, but I encountered errors. Can you help me with a good code?

Various php codes with css